# Why would 1-ethenyl-2,6-dimethylbicyclo[2.2.0]hexane give off 8 H1 signals?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

[image: 1-ethenyl-2,6-dimethylbicyclo[2.2.0]hexane]

I am trying to figure out this problem, and can only find seven signals, two from the double bond, one from the single bond attached to the double, there is symmetry, so one signal on the methyl, one on the carbon in the ring, and attached to the methyl, one on the bottom left carbon, and one on the middle bottom.

Comment: Think about the 3D structure of this molecule. Are the protons on the [4] rings all in the same environment?

Comment: The molecule contains six protons from $2$ $\ce{CH3}$, the $2$ times $2$ protons form $2$ secondary atoms (in cycles), then three tertiary carbon atoms (in cycles), and three $\ce{H}$ atoms on the double bond. Total $6 + 4 + 3 + 3 = 16$ H atoms.

Comment: The structure as drawn does not represent a *single* unique 3D structure but several structures. The bicyclic ring is likely to be fairly rigid so both the hydrogens and methyls on the ring can be locked in position above or below the ring. Whichever structure is intended, this matters for the NMR shift of the hydrogens. Try building a 3D structure and counting the distinct hydrogens.